# подскажите как перебрать массив объектов и вывести (es6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
    effects: [{
  effect_1: [{
    name: 'длительность:',
    action: '3',
  }, ],
  effect_2: [{
    name: 'урон за долю недостающего здоровья:',
    action: '0.25/0.5/0.75/1',
  }, ],
  effect_3: [{
    name: 'замедление передвижения:',
    action: '25%/30%/35%/40%',
  }, ],
  effect_4: [{
    name: 'замедление атаки:',
    action: '25/30/35/40',
  }, ],
}, ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял, то вот рекурсивная функция, которая перебирает объект, который содержит в себе массив объектов, который содержит в себе массив объектов и так далее...

```
function parseOb (obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Object) {
        for (let key in obj) {
            if (obj[key] instanceof Array || obj[key] instanceof Object) {
                parseOb(obj[key]);
            } else {
                console.log(obj[key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```